# How do I perform an action on each element of a list and put the results in a new list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

Hey I'm having a problem trying to figure this out:

Lets start out with a list with elements and a blank list.

```
L = [a, b, c]  
BL = [  ]
```

What I need to do is  perform a task on L[0] and have the result put into BL[0].
Then perform a task on  L[1] and have the result put into BL [1].
And then of course the same with the last element in the list. Resulting in

```
L = [a, b, c]
BL =[newa, newb, newc]
```

I hope you understand what I'm trying to figure out. I'm new to programming and I'm guessing this is probably done with a for loop but I keep getting errors.

Ok SO I here's the what I tried. Note: links is a list of links.

```
def blah(links):
   html = [urlopen( links ).read() for link in links]
   print html[1]
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scraper.py", line 60, in <module>
main()
File "scraper.py", line 51, in main
getmail(links)
File "scraper.py", line 34, in getmail
html = [urlopen( links ).read() for link in links]
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 86, in urlopen
return opener.open(url)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 177, in open
fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.py", line 1032, in unwrap
url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Can you please post your code so far and the error you are getting?

Comment: I know it might seem like a sidestep, but it's really worth your time to go through a tutorial, like the [official one](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  You don't have to understand it all, but at least chapters 3-5 are fundamental, and they'll help you know at least what sort of things you can do, and therefore what to search for help on.

Comment: `html = [urlopen( links ).read() for link in links]`: I think you mean `html = [urlopen(link).read() for link in links]`.  Think about what `links` is, and how `urlopen(links)` could generate the error message you see.

Comment: Good call there.. Thank you again DSM

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple, do this:

```
BL = [function(x) for x in L]
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this .. Maybe its the function I'm using that is causing the problem.

Comment: This was the easiest way thank you cupid it was me screwing up the syntax :)

Answer (score 5):

> Ok SO I heres the what i tried.. Note: links is a list of links.

```
html = [urlopen( links ).read() for link in links]
```

Here, you have asked Python to iterate over `links`, using `link` as a name for each element... and with each `link`, you call `urlopen`... with `links`, i.e. the entire list. Presumably you wanted to pass a given `link` each time.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about list comprehensions.

```
BL = [action(el) for el in L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few different approaches, all assuming `L = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `BL = []` when they're first run.

```
# Our function
def magic(x):
    return 'new' + x

#for loop - here we loop through the elements in the list and apply
# the function, appending the adjusted items to BL
for item in L:
    BL.append(magic(item))

# map - applies a function to every element in L. The list is so it
# doesn't just return the iterator
BL = list(map(magic, L))

# list comprehension - the pythonic way!
BL = [magic(item) for item in L]
```

Some documentation:

- [For](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)
- [Map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map)
- [List comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

You make a function, that does all the operations you want and use map function

```
def funct(a): # a here is L[i]
     # funct code here
     return b #b is the supposed value of BL[i]
BL = map(funct, L)
```

Comment: @BlaXpirit: it will in Python 2.

Comment: @DSM Oh, I know, but the OP didn't specify that they were using an outdated version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
x = 0
for x in range(len(L)):
    BL.append(do_something(x))
```

not as succinct as some answers, but easy for me to understand.

mad changes per comments below.

Comment: You `append` something to your list, you don't assign to it. So `BL.append(x) = do_something(L)` is wrong, it should be `BL.append(do_something(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

A useful tool here is functional programming. Python supports some higher order functions which can solve this problem.

The function in particular that we want to use is called [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)). A few of the answers here use map, but none fully embrace the functional approach. To do so, instead of using your standard python 'def' to create a function, we will use 'lambda' which is used in functional programming. This allows us to solve your problem nicely in one line.

To see more about why lambdas are useful go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-python-lambdas-are-useful). We will solve your problem as follows:

```
r = map(lambda x: urlopen(x).read(), L)
```